# Formatting values to show on map ui5 app failed

Tags: sapui5

I would like to read information from Address.Json model that looks like the following:

```html
{
  "Street": "Wall St",
  "Zip": "10005",
  "City": "New York",
  "Country": "United states"
}
```

display them in Object.view.xml as an image:

```html
<Image class="sapUiSmallMargin" src="{
                    parts: [
                        '/address/Street',
                        '/address/Zip',
                        '/address/City',
                        '/address/Country'
                    ],
                    formatter: '.formatter.formatMapUrl'
                }" />
```

and format the URL in formatter.js in order for it to be shown on a map in the ui5 app:

```js
sap.ui.define([
    'sap/base/security/encodeURL'
], function (encodeURL) {
    "use strict";

    return {
        /**
         * Formats an address to a static google maps image
         * @public
         * @param {string} sStreet the street
         * @param {string} sZIP the postal code
         * @param {string} sCity the city
         * @param {string} sCountry the country
         * @returns {string} sValue a google maps URL that can be bound to an image
         */
        formatMapUrl: function(sStreet, sZIP, sCity, sCountry) {
            var sBaseUrl = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?zoom=13&size=640x640&markers=";
            var sEncodedString = encodeURL(sStreet + ", " + sZIP +  " " + sCity + ", " + sCountry);
            return sBaseUrl + sEncodedString;
        }


    };

});
```

Unfortunately I cannot get the map to be shown on the app because of the parameters in the formatter are undefined:
[image: Error]

Therefore the map section on the app is empty:
[image: EmptyMap]

Does anyone have an idea how I can fix it and why the code I wrote does not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a model to the view in order to bind to it. See the follwoing example.

Controller.js:

```
onInit: function () {
    var oModel = new JSONModel({
        "Street": "Wall St",
        "Zip": "10005",
        "City": "New York",
        "Country": "United states"
    });
    // Adds JSONModel with name 'addressModel' to the view so you can bind to it
    this.getView().setModel(oModel, "addressModel");
}
```

View.xml:

```
<Image
    class="sapUiSmallMargin"
    src="{
        parts: [
            'addressModel>/Street',
            'addressModel>/Zip',
            'addressModel>/City',
            'addressModel>/Country'
         ],
         formatter: '.formatter.formatMapUrl'
     }"
  />
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! after I adjusted the code, I can see in debugging mode that the parameters have values but the map is still not showing, do you have an idea why?

Comment: I'm not sure that you can simple point the src of an Image to google maps, where did you see it done that way ? Maybe this [guide](https://sapyard.com/advance-sapui5-16-integration-of-google-maps-javascript-api-with-sapui5-app/) helps you.

Comment: I am following this [guide](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/1.32.9/docs/guide/6fdf0acd0bc24ffdad327cf7e6f9e7e0.html) that it might be a bit old but thought it can still work with some adjustments.
I will check the guide you recommended me. thanks

Comment: Try to access the map directly [link](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?zoom=13&size=640x640) (or in your application you should see the request to google maps in the network tab as well) and you will see that you get a response with an error saying that you are missing an API key. Read google maps api documentation in order to know how to add the key to your request.

Comment: Bonus tip: When google send you to an old versino of the documentation (like the guide you liked is for version 1.32.9), you can replace the version in the URL with a '#' to get the newest one. [Your guide in new version](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/6fdf0acd0bc24ffdad327cf7e6f9e7e0)

Comment: Very useful tip! and yes it denied the access because of a missing API key like you said, I will get busy with the guide you send me and thank you again for your support!

Comment: Bonus tip 2: Don't just rely on guides but read documenation too ;) [Google Maps API Documenation - How to get an API Key ?](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key) See this on how to get the key and the next chapter 'Adding markers'